# get youtube download link [ 4k , 1080px ] use API v3

Tags: youtube

I try To get youtube Video link from

http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=XXXXXXXX

But 1080 px and 4k is not in the list So how i can get links for this resolution

api v3 not allow to get url

Comment: any answer acn  help ?

Answer (score 3):

This function could done the job

```
<?php
function get_youtube($id)
{
    $data = file_get_contents('http://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=' . $id . '&el=vevo&fmt=18&asv=2&hd=1');

    parse_str($data , $details);
    $my_formats_array = explode(',' , $details['adaptive_fmts']);
    $avail_formats[] = '';
    $i = 0;
    $ipbits = $ip = $itag = $sig = $quality_label = '';
    $expire = time();

    foreach ($my_formats_array as $format) {
         parse_str($format);
         $avail_formats[$i]['itag'] = $itag;
         $avail_formats[$i]['quality'] = $quality_label;
         $type = explode(';', $type);
         $avail_formats[$i]['type'] = $type[0];
         $avail_formats[$i]['url'] = urldecode($url) . '&signature=' . $sig;
         parse_str(urldecode($url));
         $avail_formats[$i]['expires'] = date("G:i:s T", $expire);
         $avail_formats[$i]['ipbits'] = $ipbits;
         $avail_formats[$i]['ip'] = $ip;
         $i++;
     }
     return $avail_formats;
}
$qualitys = get_youtube($_GET['id']);

foreach($qualitys as $video)
{
    //echo "<a href='" . $video['url'] . "'>" . $video['quality'] . "-" . $video['type'] .  "</a></br>"; //print all resolution
    // for getting 1080p only
    if($video['quality']=='1080p' && $video['type']=='video/mp4'){
        echo "<a href='" . $video['url'] . "'>" . $video['quality'] . "-" . $video['type'] .  "</a></br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks ...i try get_video_info but even this not get me the link so how i can use preg_match to get right itag ?

Comment: I have added the function above

Comment: waw it`s work but tell my about these  parameters 
&el=vevo&fmt=18&asv=2&hd=1
and 4k like this can i get 4k link ????

Comment: The function already get all resolution, uncomment this line     //echo "<a href='" . $video['url'] . "'>" . $video['quality'] . "-" . $video['type'] .  "</a></br>"; //print all resolution

Comment: ya i know that but i need a way to get both audio & video in videos > 720p