# Get download link for YouTube videos which have signature

Tags: php, youtube

So I've been working on a script to download youtube videos.

It works, but I have a problem with videos having a signature.

I can fetch all its video qualities and I get the download link, but the download just gives me the following error:

> Access to r4---sn-25glenes.googlevideo.com was denied You don't have
> authorization to view this page. HTTP ERROR 403

but if I try downloading the same video with `saveform()`, it works just fine.
So what's the problem and how can I solve it?

PS: I'm working in native PHP.

Comment: Links to code or problems is not good as a problem description. Make an effort to move all relevant information in the question itself

Comment: okay in this post i asked abut fetch all quality
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45927434/get-youtube-download-link-4k-1080px-use-api-v3
so i use it so the problem is can`t download some kind of videos

Comment: Any help , idea ???